# Wap to print Below Code without using any predefined String Functions

Tags: java

```
package com.sunglowsys.Domain;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str;
        System.out.println("Enter the String");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        str=sc.next();
        char ch[]=str.toCharArray();
        int len=ch.length;
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
        {
            if(ch[i]==ch[i+1])
            {
                ch[i]=ch[i+1];
            }
            else
            {
                for(ch[i]='a';ch[i]<='z';)
                {
                    ch[i]=(char)(ch[i]+32);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

we can take any input like

eg. raamraamraaaaam

OUTPUT:-
RamRamRam

Comment: isn't `.toCharArray()` a "predefined String function"?

Comment: try sc.nextLine();

Comment: Surely this code will give you an OutOfBoundsException

Comment: Scary Wombat can you please make it correct?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rules for capitalization?

Comment: What is the idea with this "loop" `for(ch[i]='a';ch[i]<='z';)` ? This seems a bad idea if you get numbers

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regular expression for this purpose:

```
Find:    ([A-Za-z])\1+
Replace: $1
```

**Sample code:**

```
String input = "raamraamraaaaam";
input = input.replaceAll("([A-Za-z])\\1+", "$1");
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
ramramram
```

Comment: Almost *eg. raamraamraaaaam OUTPUT:- RamRamRam*

Comment: I don't think the OP actually wants camel case.

Comment: @ScaryWombat In the general case, what logic would we even be using to identify `ram` as being a substring?  This is almost like a totally different question.

Comment: Maybe just `R` should be uppercase ;-)  Sorry I saw him messing about with `ch[i]=(char)(ch[i]+32);` which of course does not make sense

Comment: I don't want to use any predefined String function "replaceAll" like that

Comment: @danishsharma Then you will need to clean up your current code.  The answer I gave is far preferable, at least if you were going to put this into production in an actual piece of software.